# изменить текст при нажатии кнопки

Tags: android

Есть кнопка которая при нажатии издаёт звук, но при долгом нажатии открывает активити, я попытался вставить код для изменения текста при нажатии кнопки, но вместо этого else отказывается работать

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private long down;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView textView;
    ImageButton blocker;


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buttons);

        findViewById(R.id.blocker).setOnTouchListener(this);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

 blocker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - down < 350)
                        play(R.raw.blocker);
                //не работает textView.append("TEXT");
                    else
                        openNewActivity();
            }
        });
}

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case ACTION_DOWN:
                down = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        return false;
    }
    
public void openNewActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, supply_system.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void closeactivity(View view){
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}

    }
```

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста больше контекста, потому что сейчас вы хотите чтобы читающие сами определили откуда у вас берется и как меняется переменная `down`, очевидно у вас всегда при выполнении кода условие в if == true, значит нужно понять как его сделать false

Comment: @Andrew, изменил шапку

Comment: то есть правильно ли я понимаю что на длинное нажатие вам нужно play(...) вызывать, а на короткое активность открывать? просто можно добавить два слушателя на кнопку длинного и короткого нажатия как мне кажется и все

Comment: @Andrew, у меня таких кнопок 9 и код тогда получится большим, но вы не всё правильно поняли при нажатии у меня  play(...) вызывается и текст должен изменится  а на длинное активити открывается

Comment: по поводу кол-ва кнопок и размера кода - можно вынести все слушатели в отдельные переменные и просто потом привязывать к кнопкам, в самих слушателях сделать switch-case по view.id и все, как вот здесь например показывается - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-click-events-button-android/, вам нужно добавить изначально два слушателя длинного и короткого нажатий, и посмотреть что и как будет работать в контексте вашей задачи, потому что на мой взгляд хардкодить например 350 не лучшая идея)

Comment: Идея неплохая, может в будущем перепишу весь код, но может вернёмся к textView?)

Comment: в вашем случае это не имеет значения) то есть вы можете просто использовать свой view вместо button и все

Comment: Нет подождите, то есть вы хотите сказать что с моим кодом, это не возможно реализовать.
Или если можно то нужно переписать весь код?

Comment: Типо что нужно вставить чтобы всё заработало

Comment: я не могу сказать с 100% уверенностью что нужно все переписывать, просто не имея кода под рукой я могу только допускать возможное решение, вам ничего по логике переписывать не нужно будет, просто добавьте другие слушатели и все) это же не все

Comment: ну как добавить обычный слушатель я знаю, но как добавить длинный и короткий?

Comment: короткий есть уже, вот длинный например - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911543/9363441

Comment: @Всё спасибо, всё получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно удалить метод currentTimeMillis и использовать setOnLongClickListener

```
blocker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    play(R.raw.blocker);
                textView.append("TEXT");
        }

    });
    blocker.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            openNewActivity();
            return true;
        }
    });
```